# Как сделать transition только для transform scale?

Tags: css, css3, css-animation, animate

Я имею popup, который имеет следующие свойства

```
transition: 0.2s ease transform;
transform: scale(0.8) translate(-50%, -50%);
```

При открытом варианте он имеет свойства

```
transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Получается что popup выезжает как бы слева снизу чуть-чуть и выполняет scale, так как анимация стоит на весь `transform`. Вопрос, как сделать анимацию только для `transform scale`, и при этом не учитывать `transform translate`?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, так не получится сделать. Можно спозиционировать popup без `translate(-50%,-50%)`. Выложите код, может чего и придумается.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это можно сделать с CSS-переменными. Наведите на надпись Hover, так можно увидеть нужный эффект.

```css
:root {
  --scale--ratio: 0;
}

.block {
  transform: scale(var(--scale--ratio)) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.hover:hover + .block {
  --scale--ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
  Hover
</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Обалденно, спасибо :)